# Is there a more efficient way of extracting a partial sum from a given number of dictionary values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary in the format `key:("string", int)` that I am iterating through from different starting positions.

A number of things are successfully happening with each iteration, however, I would like to pull out a sum of the integer values for the whole dictionary and a sum of the integer values from the beginning of the dictionary to the 'starting position'.

Is there a way to do this through a comprehension as I have done with the `total_sum` or is this already the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

CODE:

```
fruit_dict = {
    "a":("apple", 64),
    "b":("pear", 100),
    "c":("orange", 44),
    "d": ("lettuce", 4930),
    "e": ("blueberries", 37),
    "f": ("tomatoes", 75)
}

start = 2  # this is the starting position

lst_fruit_dict = list(fruit_dict)[start:]

total_sum = sum(v[1] for k, v in fruit_dict.items())

partial_sum = 0

for i in lst_fruit_dict:  # Partial Sum calculator (the bit I am trying to get more efficient)
    partial_sum += fruit_dict[i][1]
```

Comment: Seems pretty efficient to me.  Dict comprehension is still looping either way.

Comment: is there a reason you have dict as your external structure here? with a,b,c,d,e .. wouldn't a list be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(x[1] for x in list(fruit_dict.values())[start:])
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I couldn't wrap my head around how the comprehension worked. I know it is supposed to be easier to understand but I think in this case I can read it better without the comprehension.

Thank you though - I learned something :)

Comment: Feel free to accept it as the correct answer so others can benefit in the future!  Thanks.